# touchesBegan to dismiss a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I have a ViewController with a full screen UIImageView. I've hidden statusBar and NavigationBar, so there is no way to go back but tapping somewhere.

So i was thinking to go back just using this touchesBegan

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{    
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I also tried to use this way

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)];
    [imageFrame addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    imageFrame.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:image];

    [tapRecognizer release];
}
```

I got stuck there, with this full screen image and i can't go back.
How can I dismiss the viewcontroller?

Comment: Some ideas for what? You haven't told us what the problem is. Maybe touchesBegan not called? Are you looking for a best practice?

Comment: Well... nothing works. I mean, i got stuck there whit this full screen image and i can't go back. I'll edit my question, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a navigation bar I'm assuming that you did a pushViewController to start this view controller?  In which case you would want

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to dismiss the controller.

Comment: Right! I couldn't see that. Thanks a lot. Just one more thing: I've hidden statusBar and NavigationBar, so when I pop this view, they are hidden also in the old view. Is setting them back in `viewDidAppear` the only way to solve this issue, or you can suggest me something better?

Comment: I would actually recommend doing in viewWillAppear, but yes that's the only way I know of to restore Nav Bar visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Of course your solution assumes that the image view is in fact a modal view controller presented with `presentModalViewController:animated:` somewhere.

My suggestion would be to have a UIButton placed on top of your image view and sized the same. Hook up its Touch Up Inside to your go-back method and then set its alpha to 0 or Hide it through IB or properties. The button won't be displayed but it'll still receive touch events.

Comment: I tried with the button but it wasn't working. I solved with Alan Moore Solution. Your solution was smart! I think I'll use it somewhere else. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ...Now I'm curious—why did you try to dismiss a modal view controller if you never presented one?

Comment: I was erroneous thinking I used presentModalViewController:animated! I'm working since this morning and now it's almost 1 A.M. here... I should go to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You should call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: on the parent view controller, and not on the one you wanna hide.

Also make sure to set the UIImageView's userInteractionEnabled property to yes, because unlike regular UIView's it doesn't answer touch events by default.

Comment: I forgot to enable the userInteraction on the UIImageView, but that wasn't the main problem. Thanks anyway.